# Laravel update multiple records at once

Tags: mysql, laravel, performance, sql-update

I have a mysql database table with 1000000 records. I wanted to update one column in each row.

**I tried**:

```
public function methodWorking()
{
    $properties = Property::with('requests')->get();
    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        $property->number_of_request = count($property->requests);
        $property->save();
    }
}
```

This one is working but, it's very bad in performance wise.

**I wanted to write a code like this:**

```
public function methodExpect()
{
    $properties = Property::with('requests')->get();
    $property_array = [];
    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        $property->number_of_request = count($property->requests);
        $property_array[] = $property;
    }

    Property::save($property_array);
}
```

Is it possible with laravel ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

as I know, No way to do bulk updates in one query with MySQL. You can use something inside a loop like putting `Property::save($property_array);` inside your `foreach`.

for more details see [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/bulk-update?page=1)

Comment: you can easily update many records at once in MySQL, like this `update users set name='same name for all' where status='removed'`

Answer (score 0):

Changing all (or most) rows often indicates a poor schema design.  Would you like to tell us what the column contains and why it needs a mass change?

Consider removing that column from the table -- then provide the value some other way.

Yes, `UPDATE` of a million row table takes a long time.  This is because the old copy of each row is held on to, just in case there needs to be a `ROLLBACK`.

To chunk the table, doing it in manageable pieces, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LaravelBatch](https://github.com/mavinoo/laravelBatch) it's very helpful (tested on 10 000 records )